# Two different angles whose amplitudes are in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ have the same sine. What is the sum of their amplitudes?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Two different angles whose amplitudes are in the interval $[0,2\pi]$
>   have the same sine. What is the sum of their amplitudes?
>
> A. $\pi$
>   $$\\$$
>    B. A multiple of $\pi$
>   $$\\$$
>    C. A multiple of $2\pi$
>   $$\\$$
>    D. $2\pi$

I know that the amplitudes of these angles have to be $\alpha$ and $\pi-\alpha$ and so

$$(\pi-\alpha)+\alpha = \pi$$

But my book says the solution is B. I can't understand how that is though, as I couldn't seem to find any 2 diferent anges of amplitude within the given interval for which the sum would be a multiple of $\pi$.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Have the same sine as in exactly the same or same numerical value disregarding negative signs. Because $\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ produce the same answer in sine and are $\pi/2$ apart

Comment: The angles could be bigger than $\pi$.

Comment: $0$ and $2\pi$ have the same sine.

Comment: If your angles are $\sin \frac {5\pi}{4} = \sin \frac {7\pi}{4} = -\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}$  So $3\pi$ is in the solution set.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the amplitudes of these angles have to be $\alpha$ and $\pi-\alpha$ ...

That is not true.
The angles could be $\pi + \alpha$ and $2\pi - \alpha$, 
where $0\leq \alpha \leq \frac\pi2.$ Then the sine of either 
$\pi + \alpha$ or $2\pi - \alpha$ will be zero (if $\alpha = 0$)
or negative.